# Set up NAT between Docker networks

Tags: networking, docker, nat

My goal is to run two Docker containers on separate networks and have my host (Ubuntu 22.04) perform NAT so that the first network can reach the second.

My setup:

```bash
docker network create network1
docker network create network2

docker run --rm -it --network network1 ubuntu:22.04 bash

# In other terminal
docker run --rm -it --network network2 ubuntu:22.04 bash
```

The first container has an address of 172.19.0.2 and the second has an address of 172.20.0.2.

Running `ip addr` on my host, I see that the interfaces are `br-deadbeef` and `br-feedbeef`, respectively.

I then run

```bash
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -i br-deadbeef -o br-feedbeef -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i br-feedbeef -o br-deadbeef -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br-feedbeef -j MASQUERADE
```

on the host as root.

However, `ping 172.20.0.2` from the first container doesn't succeed.  Running Wireshark on the host shows the ICMP packet on the `br-deadbeef` network going from 172.19.0.2 to 172.20.0.2 but there's no reply.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the following `iptables` rules:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source          destination
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere          anywhere
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere          anywhere
...

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source          destination
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE2  all  --  anywhere          anywhere
...

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (3 references)
target     prot opt source          destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere        anywhere
...

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source          destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere        anywhere
```

If you run `iptables` with the verbose option (`-v`), you'll see that the `DROP` target under `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2` refers to the `br-deadbeef` interface (there's a `DROP` rule right under it for `br-feedbeef`).

Since you added your rules with `-A`, they were appended to the bottom of the chain which means that the jump to `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1` and hence to `DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2` took priority.

A simple fix would be to add your rules with `-I` instead.  This will insert them at the top of the chain.